# Width, text align and margin code not working for <a> code in css

Tags: html, css, width

So far the only codes that are working are color, padding and font codes. But when i try to add width or align the code to the right it doesent work?
html code:

```
<a href="https://www.football.london/chelsea-fc/transfer-news/juventus-chelsea-vlahovic-transfer-discount-27288176"><b>Juventus offer Chelsea huge Dusan Vlahovic transfer discount if Todd Boehly hands over £97m star.</b></a>
```

css code:

```
a{
    font-size: 20pxpx;
    color: hotpink;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 900px;
    margin-top: 1900px;
    }
```

I tried changing the width and switching over to max-width and several other things so far nothing has worked

Comment: Does adding `display: block` or `display: inline-block` to the styles help?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `display: block` because `a` tags are `display:inline` by default and inline elements don't obey width, height, margin and padding rules. There's also `display: inline-block` and `display: inline-flex` depending on what you need.